# Windows running 2 different version JVMs in Windows for different browsers?

Tags: windows, jvm

Using windows xp/7/vista.  Is it possible and if so how; can I run 2 different versions of Java so 2 different browsers (firefox/chrome/IE/anyother) can use the specific JVM.

Without the use of Virtual Environments of course.

thanks

Comment: why do you need to do this? java6 -> java7 has almost no compatibility issues. well, none that i'm aware of at least, and oracle says just about all java6 code will run on java7 without any changes.

Comment: 2 different companies have applets that require a specific version of java else it doesn't load.

Comment: yuck... sounds like they hard coded in a check for the java version :/  -- it's not a real dependency then as it sounds... but more an artificial dependency.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you should be able to install both the Oracle JRE version 6 and version 7 on the same system (and both the x86 and x86_64 binaries), then using Firefox you can enable/disable a specific version in the Tools → Add-ons → Plugins page.

However, if you want to run 2 different revision of the same JRE version, I think it's not possible. You may be able to install one then copy the plugin it has installed in the Firefox' plugins folder, then install the other and put the older plugin back in the plugins folder (with a different name) but I'm not sure if it would work.